# Theming Site off-line page

Tags: theming, 6, maintenance-mode

Is there any way to theme or override the Site off-line page?

The page with below massage:

> **The site is currently not available due to technical problems. Please try again later. Thank you for your understanding.**

This page uses Garland by default and it has Drupal logo on the page.
I would like to remove this Drupal logo and also change the texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are 2 templates files that handle this in your theme:

1. **maintenance-page.tpl.php:** The theming template used for when your site is in maintenance mode.
2. **maintenance-page--offline.tpl.php:** The theming template used for when your site doesn't have database connectivity.

Read [Theming the Drupal maintenance page](https://www.drupal.org/node/195435) on d.o for more information.